# Horizontal Scrolling Screenshot

Tags: windows-10, screenshot

Is there a way to take a horizontal scrolling screenshot?

I am using a web-app and would like to take a wider screenshot including all the columns in the bottom pane. The problem here is that I can't use the right arrow or even PageUp/PageDown... I have to click on the scroll bar. Maybe there is an Autohotkey script where I can choose where to click for paging?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to work around the issue:

1. Take multiple screenshots, and combine them manually, or use an app such as [Hugin](https://hugin.sourceforge.io/) to stitch them automatically.
2. Print the web page to PDF. Firefox has a Print Preview that allows for scaling and changing paper size and orientation, so the whole table can be made to fit the page. Other browsers may have a similar feature or add-on. Then convert the PDF to JPEG, PNG or other desired format.

[image: Firefox Print to PDF dlg]

Comment: Yeah #1 is the best workaround for now.
Currently even this was closed: https://github.com/ShareX/ShareX/issues/3124
The only capture app that does horizontal captures is Snagit but I do not think it supports webapps... need some functionality that will click a specific point automatically.